# “Can” vs “Able to”: People/Animals vs. Inanimate Objects

Tags: verbs, modal-verbs, nuance, animacy

I’m wondering if the English grammar “rule” given below, which I have heard from numerous non-native speakers, has any validity.

> “can” is used for people, animals, and inanimate objects.
>
> “able to” is　not used for inanimate objects, only for people and animals (animate objects).

Is this an accurate description of current usage? Was it maybe a prescriptive rule from long ago?

Just a quick Google search for “is able to” and “science” shows the following, and all from prestigious publications or institutions:

> In this situation the neuron is able to form new connections.
>
> The material is able to store the gas at a much higher concentration
>
> The human brain is able to recognise a familiar object
>
> The enzyme is able to go on chewing up
>
> The new compound, Pentobra, is able to easily punch holes

Comment: There exists no such stricture in English grammar. Apart from that, this issue isn't even about grammar. I am able to discern no reason why this question can qualify for serious consideration.

Comment: Where did you read this "rule" and those non-native speakers who told you this were probably teasing you. E.g., *Last night, my [car wasn't able to start](https://www.google.com/search?q=car+wasn%27t+able+to+start&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla:en-US:official&client=firefox-a&channel=rcs#rls=org.mozilla:en-US:official&channel=rcs&q=%22car+wasn%27t+able+to+start%22), despite all the recent repairs I had done* (Please ignore Google results, the figure is irrelevant and misleading, I just wanted to show that you *can* use *able to* with inanimate objects.

Comment: The relevant "rule" doesn't involve a distinction between animate and inanimate subjects but between _able_ and _capable_ (or in negative form, _unable_ and _incapable_). Please see the question [What's wrong with 'Bananas are unable to grow in cold countries'?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/222480/whats-wrong-with-bananas-are-unable-to-grow-in-cold-countries/222560#222560) for a discussion of this old and extremely dubious distinction.

Comment: I don't think an inanimate object is "able" to do anything. For example: the recipe is able to prevent heart disease. The correct phrasing would be: the recipe can possibly prevent heart disease.

Answer (score 3):

As an American English speaker for almost 6 decades, I have never heard this rule, nor does it make much intuitive sense.  The examples given all seem entirely appropriate current usage.

Comment: As an English speaker for more than seven decades, I come across features of the language of which I have been unaware often enough to think the fact that I haven’t come across something before does not entitle me to be certain I am right without some research.

Answer (score 0):

"Can" and "Able" are very different, it's like saying can you go to the restroom or may you (are you able to)!
 An inanimate object obviously cannot do anything, though people sometimes misspeak. In the Show Fate/Last Encore one of the main characters talks about how anything can have an ability and even in a show where magic exist "even this sword has an ability" it's still not true.

Just as the difference stated, however many of your examples can be used either way, as the brain can and is able to do things. It would have been better to use can and may.

Comment: The OP was asking about the "be able to" meaning of "can", not "may" which is a different meaning of "can". Please provide references to back up your statements.

Comment: A bridge can make travel between islands a lot easier. If it is able to take the amount of traffic that follows.

Answer (score 0):

The [NMT Crane Hire information website](http://www.nmtcranes.co.uk/much-can-mobile-crane-lift/) uses "able" when referring to tower cranes which are inanimate machines. In fact the third paragraph of the webpage uses "can" and "able" pretty well interchangeably.

> Before we start detailing specific load charts, let’s add in some context for comparison. In the construction of buildings, the typical tower crane **can** lift an unsupported weight of around 20 tonnes, depending on the conditions, while still being **able** to move the object around with relative ease.

Of course NMT isn't a definitive language authority, it's a crane hire company, but it was the first one I came to when searching for crane capacity and the page is written in good, if informal, English.

The word 'able' is used to refer to inanimate objects (particularly machines and materials) very frequently in colloquial speech, often as a synonym for 'can'. I would need to be told by a very authoritative source that such a rule existed before I stopped doing so.

Answer (score 0):

I believe it maybe a prescriptive rule from long ago, but that doesn't make it invalid or incorrect. I follow the rule, as did my predecessors.
Interestingly, in most cases when "able" is incorrectly used instead of "capable," it's easier to rephrase using "can," which also simplifies the language.